# create excel xlsx file from dataset

Tags: c#

i know this ([Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c))and i am using excel libray([http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c))

By this i can create xls file but i need xlsx file.pls help me.

Comment: What do you miss in the answers of the above post you mentioned? There were some alternatives given for creating xlsx files.

Comment: you are write but is it possible to do it with excellibrary

Answer (score 0):

workbook.Save(file);

there will be an option to specified which format u want in 'Save' method